# google maps api v3 library usage for places auto complete as well as map creation for address

Tags: php

> I was unable to find the solution using api v3 library but done that with google maps api. if some one have any idea please guide me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i had done my task but not completely using api. I am looking for any available configuration for this without using external script.